# OS Error occurred when reading all the jpeg image files in a folder by using Python language in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to read all the jpeg images in my folder. But it throws an error.

```
import os
import sys
import random
import math
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from shutil import copy

datafolder = r'C:\Users\ABI\Documents\Take Leap\TL\TL\*.jpeg'
categories = ["number","character"]

for category in categories:
    path = os.path.join(datafolder, *category)
    dirs = os.listdir(path)
    for img in dirs:
     img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path,img), cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
     plt.imshow(img_array, cmap = "black")
     plt.show()
    break
sys.exit()
```

---

```
OSError
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-c3f3eb12f0fc> in <module>
      15 for category in categories:
      16     path = os.path.join(datafolder, *category)
 ---> 17     dirs = os.listdir(path)
      18     for img in dirs:
      19      img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path,img), cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: 'C:\\Users\\ABI\\Documents\\Take Leap\\TL\\TL\\*.jpeg\\n\\u\\m\\b\\e\\r'
```

Comment: remove `*` --> `path = os.path.join(datafolder, category)
`?

Comment: still i am getting the same error

Comment: Could you add some info on what your directory structure looks like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With @Rakesh's comment about removing that splat asterisk, your code is still generating a path like `C:\Users\ABI\Documents\Take Leap\TL\TL\*.jpeg\number` which is wrong.

You might be looking for something like

```
import glob

data_template = r'C:\Users\ABI\Documents\Take Leap\TL\TL\{category}\*.jpeg'
# ...
for category in categories:
   path = data_template.format(category=category)
   files = glob.glob(path)
```

This will generate and use paths like `C:\Users\ABI\Documents\Take Leap\TL\TL\number\*.jpeg`.

Note the use of `glob.glob()`, which can handle wildcards unlike `os.listdir()`, which only accepts a directory.